# Which is better for adding videos? Firebase or Sqlite

Tags: sqlite, firebase, dart, flutter

I have an app in which the user should be able to store videos. I was wondering if Firebase or Sqlite would be better for the job. Please get back to me as soon as possible.

Comment: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage is made for that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unless the videos were really short then you wouldn't store them in a database. You would store them as files and store the path to the file in the database.

SQLite would be better if the data in the database is device specific and thus needed no syncing with other devices.

Firebase could be the choice if syncing the data across devices.

Comment: Do you know how I can store videos as files and store the path to the file in the database? I think I would go with Firebase so please tell me how to do this.

Comment: Sorry I've never used Firebase. Storing the path is just a matter of storing is as a string in a column that can store strings (nearly any column in SQLite).

Comment: @Coder See Günter Zöchbauer comment above: Cloud Storage for Firebase https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ and `getDownloadURL` method to get the path (https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.storage.Reference#getDownloadURL).